# How can I add Authorization and Date/time header in the below code?

Tags: java, java-8, rest

I am creating a Java Rest api to create users on Google Duo admin. I am following the documentation https://duo.com/docs/adminapi and they need auth and date/time header. I am fairly new to java can anyone guide me?

This is the updated code which I with authentication and date/time header but now getting the below error.

**UPDATED CODE**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Base64;


public class DuoAdminAPI {
    public static void POSTRequest() throws IOException {



        String userCredentials = "Username:Password";
        String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(userCredentials.getBytes()));

        String dateTime = OffsetDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME); //RFC_1123 == RFC_2822


        final String POST_PARAMS = "{\n" + "\"userId\": 101,\r\n" +
                "    \"id\": 101,\r\n" +
                "    \"title\": \"Test Title\",\r\n" +
                "    \"body\": \"Test Body\"" + "\n}";
        System.out.println(POST_PARAMS);
        URL obj = new URL("https://api-e9770554.duosecurity.com");
        HttpURLConnection postConnection = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        postConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        postConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        postConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);

        postConnection.setRequestProperty("Date", dateTime);



        postConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream os = postConnection.getOutputStream();
        os.write(POST_PARAMS.getBytes());
        os.flush();
        os.close();


        int responseCode = postConnection.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("POST Response Code :  " + responseCode);
        System.out.println("POST Response Message : " + postConnection.getResponseMessage());

        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) { //success
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    postConnection.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            // print result
            System.out.println(response.toString());
        } else {
            System.out.println("POST NOT WORKED");
        }
    }
}
```

**ERROR**

```
{
  "code": 40101,
  "message": "Missing request credentials",
  "stat": "FAIL"
}



 Response code: 401 (Unauthorized); Time: 2022ms; Content    length: 73 bytes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have read the documentation, the authorization is `Basic`:

```
String userCredentials = "username:password";
String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(userCredentials.getBytes()));
```

For date is this:

```
String dateTime = OffsetDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME); //RFC_1123 == RFC_2822
```

In their documentation they require `RFC 2822` format. We already have declared `RFC 1123` in `DateTimeFormatter`, which practically it is the same.

And this is the way you can add them in headers:

```
postConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);
postConnection.setRequestProperty("Date", dateTime);
```

Comment: I have updated the code as you suggested but now I am getting unauthorised error.

Comment: @Jhonnysins , Did you changed `userCredentials` value with your data? and You are sure it's right?

Comment: Yes I did I added integration key as my username but for password the doc say this ""Generate the HTTP Password as an HMAC signature of the request. This will be different for each request and must be re-generated each time."" I don't know how to do it cause I though secret key was the password